# rest service developed with spring does not work with angular $http

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I am relatively new to **Rest** and **angular** technologies.
I am trying to consume a rest service developed with spring using **$http** but could not make it work.

My service is similar to [Spring's
sample test service](http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting). I tried this URL with angular **$http** example in plunker, it fails with:

```
request failed / -1 error - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
```

here is the angular code -

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('httpExample', [])
  .controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
    function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
      $scope.method = 'GET';
      $scope.url = 'http-hello.html';

      $scope.fetch = function() {
        $scope.code = null;
        $scope.response = null;

        $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
          then(function(response) {
            $scope.status = response.status;
            $scope.data = response.data;
          }, function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = response.status;
        });
      };

      $scope.updateModel = function(method, url) {
        $scope.method = method;
        $scope.url = url;
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

what am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details on the error you're getting? Is it just a Javascript error, or are you receiving an HTTP error code from the server?

Comment: Please post the plunker

Comment: here is the link to plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/nBvu1GQTPSf62UcVIPa4?p=preview

Comment: Just check in the browser console if you are getting a CORS issue. If so check out other threads for how to disable CORS in Spring.